# Bounty notification with "expires in 3 days" vs bounty question "ending in 2 days"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, notifications

Besides English is not my first language, for me phrases *"expires in X days"* and *"ending in X days"* meaning the same thing.

Today I received a notification *"Your bounty on question X expires within **three days**"*:

[image]

While in the question we have *"This question has an open bounty ... ending in **2 days**"*:

[image]

Is that a *bug* or my misunderstanding?

Comment: Could be related to the fact that you have 24h after the bounty ends when you can still award it (i.e. not really expired yet).

Comment: If the bug is 3 days in notification vs. 2 days in the question page itself this is most likely because the notification "waited" in your inbox for a while; by the time you clicked it, enough time has passed. There is no time stamp for notifications so can't know for sure. If you mean the bug is with the wording i.e. "expires in..." vs. "ending in..." then you're totally right, it better be consistent but please make it clear in your question here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, I do understand what you mean. See, I visited SO yesterday night, so less than 8 hours before I visited it again today. For sure I *'received'* the notification this night/morning, and there was no one day delay, otherwise I have noticed it (the notification was marked as *"hot"*). From that sense, I can't say precisely if the problem is in one day delay of the notification system itself (hence a bug) or in the wording only (no bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My argument would be "within 3 days" is correct in either case, since 2 < 3...but to be specific:  we don't want to lie here.

Showing "ending in 3 days" would be disingenuous, since it ends in **less than** 3 days, saying that you have 3 days to answer is wrong, you do not have 3 complete days.  We round down intentionally here, since coming in **before** the deadline is much better than after it.

This notice is sent out on the hour and happens for a question when it falls just under the 3 days old threshold (meeting the "within three days")...it is behaving correctly.